# How to get projection profile of image using IMAGEMAGICK convert?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

For an example, I copied from a dissertation, PDF pg 24:

https://uknowledge.uky.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1055&context=cs_etds

---

[image]

---

I would like to use 'convert' to get the 'x' profile, the 'y' profile, or both the "x,y" profiles simultaneously. A profile would be a pixel count of data in each pixel bucket, and we are in grayscale or black/white mode [0,1] or {0,1} respectively.

Attached is a PNG of "projection-profile" example.

`convert pp.png pp.txt`

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming from your guesstimated command that you want a textual output, so try this for the 66 row-projections:

```
magick pp.png -threshold 50% -negate -crop x1 -format "%[fx:w*h*mean]\n" info:
```

**Output**

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
25
33
38
41
40
36
29
18
18
18
18
96
150
214
232
226
171
160
150
149
151
167
167
139
135
138
135
134
138
135
140
160
212
233
181
18
18
18
18
17
17
17
17
17
30
34
31
2
0
0
0
0
0
```

The command should be pretty self-explanatory. The `-negate` is to invert the image and count black instead of white pixels. The `-crop x1` is to split the image into single lines so that the ensuing `format` command runs once for each line. The `-format` command multiplies the mean of the pixels in the row by the area of the row to get the number of set pixels.

---

And this for the 399 column projections:

```
magick pp.png -threshold 50% -negate -crop 1x -format "%[fx:w*h*mean]\n" info:
```

---

If you want the graphical, histogram-style output, you could pipe to `gnuplot`. Here is the vertical projection for example:

```
magick pp.png -threshold 50% -negate -crop 1x -format "%[fx:w*h*mean]\n" info: | gnuplot -e 'plot "-" using 1: xtic(1) with histogram' -persist
```

[image]

Note that you *could* do both the horizontal and vertical projections in one go, but it's probably not worth the trouble and complexity. You could prefix the counts with `h` or `v` and filter them in `gnuplot`. Or you could write the horizontal projections to `fd:3` and vertical ones to `fd:4` and re-direct the two separately in the shell to different instances of `gnuplot`